# Azure - Process Message Files in real time

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-eventhub, azure-data-factory

I am working on Azure platform and use Python 3.x for data integration (ETL) activities using Azure Data Factory v2. I got a requirement to parse the message files in .txt format real time as and when they are downloaded from blob storage to Windows Virtual Machine under the path D:/MessageFiles/.

I wrote a Python script to parse the message files because it's a fixed width file and it parses all the files in the directory and generates the output. Once the files are successfully parsed, it will be moved to archive directory. This script runs well in local disk on ad-hoc mode whenever i need it.

Now, i would like to make this script run continuously in Azure so that it looks for the incoming message files in the directory D:/MessageFiles/ all the time and perform the processing as and when it sees the new files in the path.

Can someone please let me know how to do this? Should i use any stream analytics application to achieve this?

**Note**: I don't want to use Timer option in Python script. Instead, i am looking for an option in Azure to use Python logic only for File Parsing.

Comment: So you want it event driven?

Comment: yes... kind of... run the ETL as when the new files arrive